# Is it correct to write "..., so..."? Is it formal to use "so" in writing?

Tags: conjunctions, formality

Is it correct to write "..., so..."?
e.g.

```
You are handsome, so you are appreciated.
```

Is it correct to use "so" in formal writing? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to avoid using "so" in formal / business writing. Someone suggested "therefore" as an alternative, but in some cases that may sound too strong, as it implies an indisputable logical conclusion. I don't think your example is trying to express it that strongly.

Perhaps it's helpful to put things in a different order, and use *because* instead:

`You are appreciated, because you are handsome.`

Answer (score 1):

Including "and" is a touch more formal than "so" by itself.

> You are handsome and so you are appreciated.

Besides the already suggested "therefore" and "because", "hence" is another less commonly used option.

> You are handsome, hence you are appreciated.

A few phrases are also possible: "and for that", "and as a result"

> You are handsome and for that you are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the word "therefore" would be a good alternative.