# Using "so" in formal writing to introduce questions, and its possible alternatives

Tags: formality

Context: Suppose that in a formal academic writing we have talked about a problem and now we want to talk about its solutions. Is the following sentence appropriate for opening a paragraph?

> So what can be done about that?

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165769/is-it-correct-to-write-so-is-it-formal-to-use-so-in-writing), it has been suggested that "so" should be replaced with "therefore". However, I think here it is not appropriate. Since the formality of "so" can be opinion-based, what are the alternative to the above sentence to avoid a dispute about the style of writing? I think saying "What can be done about that?" is not the best choice after talking about the problems. "So" somehow indicates that we are done with stating the problem and now we want to talk about the solutions. Maybe the word "Now" can be a good alternative for "So" here.

Comment: *I think saying "What can be done about that?" is not the best choice after talking about the problems.* Why? It seems fine to me.

Comment: It's just a matter of taste and style. I mean I want to say "now, after we have become familiar with problems, what can be done about them?" I think it smooths the flow of writing.

Comment: "Formal" texts usually avoid acknowledging the existence of even the *writer* (style guides for technical writing usually advise against ***I*** at all, and minimising references to ***we***). Maybe it's just me, but I'd have thought with or without (almost meaningless) initial ***so*** in OP's context, ***What can be done about it**?* very strongly evokes an atmosphere of "conversational interaction" with an implicitly "personified ***second*** person" *(**you** the **reader**)* - something which style guides might well see as even *less* desirable than ***first*** person references.

Answer (score 0):

What is the solution?
How can this issue/ problem be resolved?
Consequently
In response to~
In order to confront the problem, what can be done?